# SwiftUI Button tap area not accurate but in navigationBarItems is right

Tags: button, swiftui, swiftui-button

Here use the same button view in navigationbaritem and ContentView.
have idea to solve this problem?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK7i8.jpg

```
struct myButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {  print("qwe\(Int.random(in: 1...100))") }) {
            Image( "play")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .background(Color.red)
        }
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            myButton()
                
          .navigationBarItems(leading:

            myButton()
          )
                .navigationTitle("Title")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzMrd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Natively in SwiftUI you can't use shaping on toolbar icons
(you can, but sometimes navigation bar icons loses clipshapes (after navigationLink, .sheet, .alert....)

(on *SwiftUI 2* prefer to use .toolbar{}, no .navigationBarItems() )

But, you can use SwiftUIX library [on GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX)